# Adding an orderby filter, casting postmeta with multiple keys

Tags: filters, query, post-meta, wpdb

I am using this filter to sort my query by a date field stored as text (legacy data)

```
add_filter( 'posts_orderby', 'my_posts_orderby_date', 10, 2 );
function my_posts_orderby_date( $orderby, $query ) {
    global $wpdb;
    return " CAST( $wpdb->postmeta.meta_value AS DATE ) " . $query->get( 'order' );
}
```

I need to tell this filter which meta_key to use, because it currently grabs the wrong meta key ($state_key) to sort on. How would I adjust this filter to do so?

i.e. I need to add this to the filter, somehow

```
$wpdb->postmeta.meta_key = 'tf_events_startdate'
```

Here is the original set of args, if it helps. Thank you!

```
$args = array(
            'post_type' => 'tf_events',         
            'meta_key' => $state_key,
            'meta_value' => $state_meta_value,
            'meta_query' => array( $relation, $date_query, $date_query2 ),
            'posts_per_page' => $limit, 
            'tax_query' => array( 'relation' => 'AND', $type_query, $host_query ),              
            'order' => 'ASC'
        );
```

Answer (score 0):

Got the idea from this post to change my query : [How to "orderby" the first array in a meta_query that uses multiply keys?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/17177/how-to-orderby-the-first-array-in-a-meta-query-that-uses-multiply-keys?rq=1)

I moved the state query into the larger array of queries, freeing the 'meta_key' value to be assigned to event date

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'tf_events',         
    'meta_query' => array( $relation, $date_query, $date_query2, $state_query ),
    'posts_per_page' => $limit, 
    'meta_key' => 'tf_events_startdate',
    'tax_query' => array( 'relation' => 'AND', $type_query, $host_query ),              
    'order' => 'ASC'
    );

add_filter( 'posts_orderby', 'my_posts_orderby_date', 10, 2 );
    function my_posts_orderby_date( $orderby, $query ) {
        global $wpdb;  
        return " CAST( $wpdb->postmeta.meta_value AS DATE ) " . $query->get( 'order' );
    }
```

Comment: Answer it man so people know that the answer was found.